# If a $k$-algebra $R$ is isomorphic to $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/J$ (where $J$ is an ideal), then $R$ is finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, polynomial-rings

I have a question for the following argument. My goal is to find a finite set of elements of $R$ that generate it. To that end, I let $\phi$ be the isomorphism from $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/J$ to $R$, and I let $r_i = \phi(x_i + J)$.

For $r \in R$, there exists $p \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $\phi(p + J) = r$. Now $p$ can be expressed as a sum of polynomials, so after some more manipulation I can express the image of one of those summands as:

$$\phi(p_i + J) = \phi(c_i + J)r_1^{\beta_1}\dots r_n^{\beta_n},$$

where $c_i \in k$, and $\beta_m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. How should I deal with that term $\phi(c_i + J)$?

Comment: Precise language will help here. When you say isomorphic, do you mean as rings or as $k$-algebras? Presumably your hypothesis is the latter.

Comment: I’m inclined to think it’s the latter. The following up question asks us to show that in particular there is a surjection from $k[\bf{x}]$ to $R$.

Comment: I'd agree that it's meant to be as $k$-algebras. What's the definition of a $k$-algebra morphism? This will resolve your issue with $\phi(c_i + J)$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Sorry for the late reply. I didn’t see your comment notification for some reason. I just follow the standard definition that a $k$-algebra homomorphism is a $k$-linear map. I suspect in the above, I’d have $\phi(c_i + J) = c_i$, and that the field in $k[\bf{x}] / {J}$ is $(k + J)$. Could you comment on those assertions?